# Why Geoip return int instead float?

Tags: php, geoip, maxmind

Two different servers return different latitude and longitude.

I installed GeoIp to two servers:

```
apt-get install geoip-database geoip-database-extra php-geoip
```

And made test script:

```
$ip_address = ...;
$info = geoip_record_by_name($ip_address);
var_dump($info);
```

For some Ip's, one of servers return integer instead float, for example:

```
ip:12.219.119.222
server1: [latitude] => 38 [longitude] => -97
server2: [latitude] => 37.750999450684 [longitude] => -97.821998596191

ip:172.113.184.205
server1: [latitude] => 38 [longitude] => -97
server2: [latitude] => 33.660301208496 [longitude] => -117.99919891357 

ip:91.152.191.186
server1: [latitude] => 60.175598144531 [longitude] => 24.934200286865
server2: [latitude] => 60.175598144531 [longitude] => 24.934200286865
```

server1 use Ubuntu 16.04
server2 use Ubuntu 17.10

How to fix it?

Comment: example n3: both are "float" as you say

Comment: @Leos313, and how to fix first two? I see that last correct, why first two not?